# How to encode “?” in image URL

Tags: wordpress, encode, jetpack

I checked this already and found a solution here (Q 34160546) which sadly does not work for me though, maybe anyone else has an idea?

I checked my site on pingdom and wanted to get rid of this problem they put up:

**Resources with a “?” in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:**

A bunch of jpgs are listed, but to keep it simple lets just look at my profile picture on the main homepage (right widget):

```
https://example.com/profile.jpg?w=192
```

This ? should be encoded with %3F and my question is how I can do that the best way? Within the widget code that generates the code above, I only included this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/profile.jpg" class="aligncenter" width="192">
```

Now I can’t just go ahead and write this instead, it will result in the picture not showing up:

```
<img src="https://example.com/profile.jpg%3Fw=192">
```

Can anyone tell me a quick fix for my ~25 images? Maybe it will improve the site speed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, this is possible to remove "?" from script and styles. But from the image, you need some customization.

you can use preg_replace, I did this little example for you.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.test/img/FMR.jpg?Qq_0y12h";

echo "url = $url\n\n";

$urlFormatted = preg_replace("/\?.*$/", "", $url);
echo "urlFormatted = $urlFormatted\n";

?>
```

For more information,

- [Remove character from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091344/remove-character-from-image-url/28092717#28092717)
- [PHP Remove parameters from image extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016888/php-remove-parameters-from-image-extension)
- [Removing query string in PHP (sometimes based on referrer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270677/removing-query-string-in-php-sometimes-based-on-referrer)

Or you may try this code also, not tested but this will help you. please [visit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink)

```
function remove_query_string($url) {
 return remove_query_arg('w', $url);
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'remove_query_string');
```

hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks , do you think it would actually improve the speed loading or not have much on on effect? It is just rated as F on Pingdom in red and looks like a bad thing, but maybe having the ? symbol encoded in the end wont make any noticeable difference?

I could test your code, but am not sure how to put it in since we are talking about 25 pictures and the URL would have to be replaced for each?

Comment: as per my view 'the_permalink' this hook will filter each and every permalink in your WordPress theme, so it may take much time to process each. I think without this "?" or with this will affect the same. Hope this will helps you. If it will help you please accept this. So, this will helpful for others also. :)